# Oracle Application Framework

Tags: java, sql, oracle

How i can check unicity of a field using OAF?
i have a field *Invoice-Id* and i want a function using OAF for testing the unicity using this query.

```
String Query="select count(*) from ap_suppliers where 'Condition' ";
```

if this query return a value > 0 then lunch an exception
else accept this value.

Comment: What's "unicity"?

Comment: the unicity of value entred in this field. i want to compare this value with all values exist in database

Comment: You mean is a value unique for a given column?

Comment: yes how to develop this using OAF

Comment: No i know how to develp Query but i don't know how to use it with Oracle Application Framework

Comment: Why do you want to write a query to use this instead of relying on a unique constraint? A query is unsafe in multi-user environment, won't scale and is not idiomatic.

Comment: So what is the perfect solution to test the unicity using OAF?!